# Angular 4 App served through .NET WebAPI - URL gets messed

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have an AngularJS app which is currently being served through a custom route in .net WebApi.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("angularjs")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(baseHref + "index.html");

        string htmlFile = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        // some more stuff

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(htmlFile)
        };

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response;
    }
```

The index.html file contains:

```
<base href="/baseHref/">
```

Then I enter http://localhost/angularjs and the app loads fine, the final url is: http://localhost/angularjs/#/home, which is what I want.

I'm trying to do the same with Angular 4 but I have a problem with the final URL.

The route is

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("angular4")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(baseHref4 + "index.html");

    string htmlFile = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    // some more stuff

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new StringContent(htmlFile)
    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

The index.html file contains:

```
<base href="/baseHref4/">
```

Expected: http://localhost/angular4/#/home (the route response with the injected index.html in the response)

Getting: http://localhost/baseHref4/#/home (the app being redirected after the route resolves)

It seems to be a problem with the Angular 4 app, since if I comment out the angular scripts in the index.html I will just get http://localhost/angular4/ (the injected index.html without loading the app).

Would like some help. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Probably something to do with the RouterModule, since if I set `initialNavigation: false` then it will only set the basehref after I navigate. Is there a way to change this behavior